# Subscribe on iOS tel scheme

Tags: swift, xcode, voice, tel

I have an iOS app that can perform calls.

What I need to do, is when user goes to any other 3rd party app (messanger, website in browser etc). And clicks phone number, my app should appears in list of suggested apps to perform the call.

I have added "tel" schema to "URL Schemes" but still my app is not appears.

Can you, please, help me with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, iOS never presents a list of suggested apps to perform a call/handle a URL. That exists in Android but not on iOS.

As of iOS 14, users are now able to select a non-Apple browser and email client, but still nothing for the phone app: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211336.

Comment: Hello, @pietrorea, Thank you for help.
Do you know the link to the official documentation, were apple provide us with detail information?

Comment: This may help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app

Comment: Also these are some older docs about the tel:// scheme: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1